# App Engine, Python: how to filter query by ID?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I try to get data from app engine datastore.

Filtering query by 'title' (or any other property) works:

```
obj = db.Query(PageModel).filter('title',title)[0]
```

But the same thing with ID - doesn't:

```
obj = db.Query(PageModel).filter('ID',page_id)[0]
```

I think there is something special about IDs and KEYs in datastore, but I cant find, how to implement getting data by ID.

Comment: Needs more information. Context? What are these attributes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
obj = PageModel.get_by_id(page_id)
```

instead.  This assumes that the ID you're working with is the numerical ID of a datastore key (ie, came from something like `obj.key().id()`) and not some arbitrary ID field you've added to your `PageModel`.

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id

Answer (score 2):

You can filter data by using key(s):

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import Key
key = Key('bgakaWdyc3NlcnIPCxIJRmVlZEVudHJ5GAwM')

# Match many
PageModel.all().filter('__key__ IN ', [key])
# Match one
PageModel.all().filter('__key__ = ', key)
```

However, the method get_by_id(id) is preferred when fetching one entry.